# substring operation using antcontib's properyregex task

Tags: regex, ant, regex-negation, regex-greedy, ant-contrib

I am trying to do a substring operation using antcontrib's propertyregex. Here is my original string:

```
COMPONENT:MYBuild:cat:cat
```

Im trying to extract `MYBuild` from the above string.

```
<propertyregex property="builderName"
     input="${componentLine}"
     regexp="(.*)COMPONENT:.*:"
     replace=""
     casesensitive="true"
     override="true"/>
```

But this is fetching me

```
 COMPONENT:MYBuild:cat:
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex, with [And addon Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/) it's straightforward :

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
 <property name="componentLine" value="COMPONENT:MYBUILD:cat:cat"/>
  <fl:let>
   builderName := split('${componentLine}', ':')[1]
  </fl:let>
  <echo>$${builderName} => ${builderName}</echo>
</project>
```

output :

```
 [echo] ${builderName} => MYBUILD
```

Flaka has other functions too, if you need a regex, use replace()
See Flaka [Manual](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/wiki/Manual) and [Examples](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/wiki/FlakaExamples) for details.

Comment: Hi @Rebse, 
When I use the flaka tags, im getting the following error on the if loop(line 196) that contains this string operation using flaka

/afs/btv.ibm.com/data/aes/ANT_REG/build.xml:196: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersi
onError: it/haefelinger/flaka/dep/Select (Unsupported major.minor version 49.0)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java(Compiled Code))
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java(Compiled Code))at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java(Compiled Code

Comment: you get the error "Unsupported major.minor version 49.0" because Flaka is compiled with java 1.5 and you're using an earlier java version, i.e. 1.4 - check with "java -version" in console; you should switch to an up-to-date java version, i.e. 1.6.0_33 or 1.7.0_05 also for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

One of the neat things about regular expressions is the use of `[^x]` which means any character besides `x`. This is a great thing when you have to thwart the greediness of regular expressions. For example, `[^:]*` means select all characters up to the next colon:

```
<propertyregex property="builderName"
     input="${componentLine}"
     regexp="[^:]*:([^:]*)"
     select="\1"
     override="true"/>
```

The first `[^:]*:` matches `COMPONENT:`. This says match the entire string that doesn't contain a colon, and the colon that follows it. (You see how this works?)

The next `([^:]*)` matches `MyBuild`. It's similar to the first, except it doesn't have a colon, so the colon following `MyBuild` won't be included. It's surrounded by parentheses because I want to capture it.

Instead of the `replace` parameter, I use the `select` parameter which allows me to say that I want to replace the whole string with just the first capture group (what's in parentheses).

I haven't tested this, but it should work, or at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi @David W.
I am seeing a new problem while implementing this solution. Most often the search string is COMPONENT:MYBuild:cat:cat but there can be cases where the search string is COMPONENT:MYBuild:cat:cat:cat1:cat2.

When I use the following              <propertyregex   property="firstFourParamsInComponentLine"       input="@{line}"         regexp="[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*"      select="\2"                   casesensitive="true"        override="true"/>
 in normal cases, it picks up the first four params, in other cases where there are more than 4 params, the entire sequence is selected.

Comment: I just tested the solution I gave you on `Test:one:two:three:four:five:six`. It picked `one` as it's suppose to. Are you saying that the one you want changes depending upon the number of items?

Comment: yes David. So now I have used ant flaka like the following.
<fl:let> builderName ::= split('${componentLine}', ':')[1]</fl:let>
Thanks for your replies.